# Struggling with objective-c dictionary

Tags: objective-c

Can someone please help me with what should be a pretty basic issue..

The Im trying to get the values stored in the dictionary via an array of objects (_options) with property section which is between 1 and 3

```
_sections = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @1, @"2", @2, @"3", @3, nil];
NSLog(@"sections=%lu",(unsigned long)[_sections count]);

for(Options *thisOption in _options)
    {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thisOption.section];
    NSLog(@"key=%@",key);
    NSNumber *count = [_sections objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"count=%@",count);
    }
```

my log displays sections=3, key=2 but count=(null)

Comment: You need to show what Options is for your question to make any sense.

Comment: `NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thisOption.section];` - what is the type of `thisOption.section`. If that's an integer, your format should `@"%i"` not `@"%@"`.

Comment: @rdelmar No he doesn't, you can see in his output that key is correctly being set as @"2".  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order of your objects and keys reversed in dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:.

I suggest using literals to make your code a bit more clear:

(Assuming your dictionary must be mutable)

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"1": @1, @"2": @2}];
```

(If you forget the mutable part)

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"1": @1, @"2": @2};
```

Comment: You're right, but I'm not sure literals really clarify the issue. In fact, the method name `-dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` *tells you* the order, and the OP still managed to get it wrong. The literal syntax is only intuitive if the 'key:object' syntax matches your expectations.

Comment: @Caleb I added the literals because even though you are right, it is d*@% confusing to most developers that you would ever place the object before the key.  The existence of this question is proof in the pudding.

Answer (score 1):

Your key is the string @"2", but the key in the dictionary is the NSNumber 2. Those two objects aren't the same, so when you try to look up an object with that key, it doesn't find anything and returns nil.